# how can I target with jquery this element?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to customise a Wp plugin called essential grid that has a filter to filter content. this filter buttons have the following markup:

```
<div data-filter="filter-documentary" data-fid="11" class="esg-filterbutton"><span>Documentary</span><span class="esg-filter-checked"><i class="eg-icon-ok-1"></i></span></div>
```

how can i target "data-filter="filter-documentary" with jquery? so when this button is clicked, css is applied to a div?

I have tried:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  var filterdoc = document.getElementById('[data-filter="filter-documentary"]');

  filterdoc.style.cursor = 'pointer';

  filterdoc.onclick = function() {

      $("body").addClass("filter_doc");
  };

  });
```

but is not doing nothing.

Comment: `$('[data-filter="filter-documentary"]')`

Comment: tried that, did not work. updated my code so you can see what i have tried.

Comment: Use `$('[data-filter="filter-documentary"]')` OR `document.querySelector('[data-filter="filter-documentary"]')`

Comment: " document.getElementById('[data-filter="filter-documentary"]')", by this you are trying to get element by ID. it will not work, you are targeting the attribute value.
Try this:

Comment: var filterdoc = document.querySelector('[data-filter="filter-documentary"]');
 did it :) thank you, learned new stuff today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
 $("[data-filter=filter-documentary]").css({ 
       //your css code
  });
});
```

Comment: hi jhon, thanks. the CSS goes with the standard css markup? i tried but did not work. i rather keep my css separate of the js

Comment: it is object, so use like:
$("[data-filter=filter-documentary]").css({
color:'#c34d23',
postion:'absolute'
});